# Weird disappearing dropdowns in Opera 10.51 using jQuery fadeIn and HoverIntent

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, opera

Take a look at www.sensenich.com in Opera.  I'm not sure if this is specific to my version but Opera seems to do a number on the dropdowns from the top navigation menu.

For some reason the li in the ul .subhead become transparent.  Also if you hover over .subhead it immediately disappears.

This behavior only seems to exist in Opera, otherwise the menu works great in IE6,7,8, Firefox 3.5+, Safari and Chrome.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That looks extremely weird. Could you submit a bug report on https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having weird issues with opera :hover too - I don't think it's a javascript thing because I'm using pure css for my dropdowns.  [On my site](http://ratiochristi.org/index.php?id=1052), the submenu drowpdown will trigger on hover but as you move your cursor down the menu item list the anchors (which are set to the full size of the ul in pixes) aren't clickable unless you're right over the text.  What's even weirder is that the bug is intermittent.  Sometimes it works properly and other times it doesn't.

Even the main menu has intermittent problems.  Sometimes the first time I visit the page it works fine.  Then I press refresh a couple of times (no changes on the server side) and it acts buggy.  Also, I've noticed that when I re-upload the EXACT SAME stylesheet and click refresh the main menu works fine again.  Very weird.

The menu works fine in every other browser.  There's definitely some kind of bug with opera :hover.